# php function similar to .text() jQuery method

Tags: php, jquery, html, text

Hi i was wondering if there is a function in php to take this `1<sup>o</sup>semaster` and returns me `1o semaster`
I want the same function for php as `variable.text()` method of jquery

Comment: Just to note, when using strip_tags (like the posts below state) you won't be getting `1o semaster`. You'll get `1osemaster` -- so.. that's probably just a typo, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for [strip_tags](http://www.php.net/strip_tags)

Comment: @MikulasDite: `htmlspecialchars()` is definitely not like jQuery's `.text()` (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9s7h/)), but `strip_tags()` is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = "1<sup>o</sup>semaster
echo strip_tags($test);
```